# Check if a datetime value is in an interval column pandas python

Tags: python

I've been searching google to solve this problem for a couple hour now. So I have an interval datetime column (Interval) and another column (Datetime) with datetime. I want to check ***if each row*** in (Datetime) ***is in all of*** (Interval), if it is, sum the total number and put it in a new column (Number).

Original column:

| Datetime | Interval |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 09:00:00 | (2021-12-01 08:24:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41] |
| 2021-12-01 08:01:00 | 2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41 |
| 2021-12-01 09:03:50 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42 |
| 2021-12-01 08:03:42 | (2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41] |
| 2021-12-01 08:00:12 | 2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41 |
| 2021-12-01 09:03:43 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42 |
| 2021-12-01 08:03:42 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42] |

What I want:

| Datetime | Interval | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 09:00:00 | (2021-12-01 08:24:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41] | 7 |
| 2021-12-01 08:01:00 | 2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41 | 0 |
| 2021-12-01 09:03:50 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42 | 3 |
| 2021-12-01 08:03:42 | (2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41] | 3 |
| 2021-12-01 08:00:12 | 2021-12-01 08:03:42, 2021-12-01 09:03:41 | 0 |
| 2021-12-01 09:03:43 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42 | 3 |
| 2021-12-01 08:03:42 | (2021-12-01 09:03:43, 2021-12-01 10:03:42] | 3 |

Observe that 1st row of the **datetime** column can be located in all of the 2nd column of **Interval** bringing the total to **7**. The 3rd column of the **datetime** column can be located in 3rd, 6th and 7th rows of the 2nd column **Interval** bring that total to **3** .......so on and so forth.

This is my attempt in Python:

```
For ii in dt.index:

    if dt['Datetime'].notnull():
        
        dt['Total'][ii] = sum(dt['Datetime'] in (dt['Interval']))
```

Comment: should the first one be 6?

Comment: Yes you are correct Z Li the first one should be 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over each row, and within that iterate over intervals:

```
intervals = df['Interval'].values
df['Total'] = [sum([x in y for y in intervals]) for x in df['Datetime']]
```

Comment: Am getting this error "TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: this is because you are using interval type. I have updated the code